# Delete FROM SQL Server table where DateTimeOffset greater or equal C# DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a SQL Server table containing data where each row has a name and a DateTimeOffset field.
Now I want to delete all data from the table where the DateTimeOffset field contains a value >= than a DateTime (UTC) object I have in my C# application so that I can insert new data afterwards without having duplicates in the table. Here is an example for how I am trying to do this in C#:

```
 DateTime timestamp = data.Timestamp.UtcTime; //28.10.2020 15:00:00 UTC

 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"DELETE FROM <tablename> WHERE Name = @p_name AND Time >= @p_timestamp", conn))
 {
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = "ExampleName" });
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p_timestamp", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset) { Value = timestamp });
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

After executing this statement I can still find rows in the table with the Time field "2020-10-28 15:00:00.0000000 +01:00". Why? I already tried using `SqlDbType.DateTime` or `SqlDbType.DateTime2` instead of `SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset` but that did not fix the problem. Converting the timestamp to a `DateTimeOffset` object also made no difference. The timestamp I use for this delete statement is the exact same timestamp that is later used when inserting the data so what could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you considered using a `DateTimeOffset` in your C# for the date type of `DateTime` as well? Considering your dealing with a `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server, it would seem appropriate to use the same data type in your C#.

Comment: @Larnu Yes but as I said that did not make a difference.

Comment: Don't just, however, change the line to `DateTimeOffset timestamp = data.Timestamp.UtcTime;`; that would likely set the value to the current UTC time, but with the local hosts current offset. Actually give it a `DateTimeOffset` value. For example, if it's the current time you need, that appears to be `DateTimeOffset.Now()`.

Comment: @Larnu So how should that be done correctly? I am a little too confused with all this right now to even be sure if the insert is done correctly. Is the offset in DateTimeOffset supposed to be added to the datetime part of it to get the actual UTC time or is the part without the offset the UTC time and adding the offset would result in the local time?

Comment: Reading your post, actually, you state that the value is `28.10.2020 15:00:00Z`, and you are deleting rows on are after then. `2020-10-28 15:00:00.0000000 +01:00` is `2020-10-28 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00` so that isn't *after* and so should **not** be deleted. This is just a simple misunderstanding of how timezones work.

Comment: @Larnu Is there a way to chat about this? I have way too many questions right now to discuss in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223829/discussion-between-chris-and-larnu).